# Difference between UntypedFormControl and FormControl #Angular14 #AngularMigration

Tags: formbuilder, form-control, formgroups, angular14, angular-migration

I recently migrated from Angular12 to Angular14, Angular automatically converted FormControl to UntypedFormControl in some places. I observed that in some components where I am using  FormControl  it is still written as FormControl. So I am bit confused  on which criteria or in which conditions angular converted FormControl  into UntypedFormControl and why at some places it is still FormControl. I understood that UntypedFormControl is simply pointing to FormControl with type any.

When I compared both scenarios I don't see any difference in coding and the way I am creating and using formGroup and formControl. It got me more confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Untyped is just to minimize impact on your existing code base during the migration. It is better now to use typed form for new development. And ideally convert legacy code base to typed form also if needed.

Check the detailed description on typed forms on
https://ujjwal-rajpal96.medium.com/angular-strictly-typed-vs-untyped-forms-e63cded8a228